# How to query from SQLite order by numbers in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database (android) with many columns and one is full of numbers,
And when I’m trying to query the numbers are sort in alphabetical order,
*Ex. 1, 14, 17, 2, 20, 27, 286, 34,*
How do I sort it in numerical order?

Comment: Is this column of type TEXT of INTEGER?

Comment: text,  Change to integer help’s me?

Comment: definitely, see CommonsWare answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I sort it in numerical order?

You store the data in an `INTEGER` column, rather than a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Works also on: 5.6, 5.8 ?

Comment: @user3220968: If you want floating point values, use a `REAL` column. You can read more about SQLite data types at: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

We could use more info on your db, and your current query could help us give you a better answer.

But did you try : SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME